# Optimizing a simple CPU bound function with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to understand how the multiprocessing.Pool works, and I have developed a minimal example that illustrates my question. Briefly, I am using pool.map to parallelize a CPU-bound function operating on an array by following the example [Dead simple example of using Multiprocessing Queue, Pool and Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887555/dead-simple-example-of-using-multiprocessing-queue-pool-and-locking). When I follow that pattern, I get only a modest speedup with 4 cores, but if I instead manually chunk the array into *num_threads* and then use pool.map over the chunks, I find speedup factors that vastly exceed 4x, which makes no sense to me. Details to follow.

First, the function definitions.

```
def take_up_time():
    n = 1e3
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1

def count_even_numbers(x):
    take_up_time()
    return np.where(np.mod(x, 2) == 0, 1, 0)
```

Now define the functions we'll benchmark.

First the function that runs in serial:

```
def serial(arr):
    return np.sum(map(count_even_numbers,arr))
```

Now the function that uses Pool.map in the "standard" way:

```
def parallelization_strategy1(arr):
    num_threads = multiprocessing_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_threads)
    result = pool.map(count_even_numbers,arr)
    pool.close()
    return np.sum(result)
```

Finally, the second strategy in which I manually chunk the array and then run Pool.map over the chunks (Splitting solution due to [python numpy split array into unequal subarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922395/python-numpy-split-array-into-unequal-subarrays))

```
def split_padded(a,n):
    """ Simple helper function for strategy 2
    """
    padding = (-len(a))%n
    if padding == 0:
        return np.split(a, n)
    else:
        sub_arrays = np.split(np.concatenate((a,np.zeros(padding))),n)
        sub_arrays[-1] = sub_arrays[-1][:-padding]
    return sub_arrays

def parallelization_strategy2(arr):
    num_threads = multiprocessing_count()
    sub_arrays = split_padded(arr, num_threads)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_threads)
    result = pool.map(count_even_numbers,sub_arrays)
    pool.close()
    return np.sum(np.array(result))
```

Here is my array input:

```
npts = 1e3
arr = np.arange(npts)
```

Now I use the IPython %timeit function to run my timings, and for 1e3 points I get the following:

- **serial**: 10 loops, best of 3: 98.7 ms per loop
- **parallelization_strategy1**: 10 loops, best of 3: 77.7 ms per loop
- **parallelization_strategy2**: 10 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop

Since I have 4 cores, Strategy 1 is a disappointingly modest speedup, and strategy 2 is suspiciously larger than the maximum 4x speedup.

When I increase npts to 1e4, the results are even more perplexing:

- **serial**: 1 loops, best of 3: 967 ms per loop
- **parallelization_strategy1**: 1 loops, best of 3: 596 ms per loop
- **parallelization_strategy2**: 10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop

So the two sources of confusion are:

1. Strategy 2 is way faster than the naive theoretical limit
2. For some reason, %timeit with npts=1e4 only triggers 1 loop for serial and strategy 1, but 10 loops for strategy 2.

Comment: Did you compare the results for the different strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategies aren't doing the same!

In the first strategy, the `Pool.map` iterates over an array, so `count_even_numbers` is called for every array item (since the shape of the array is one-dimensional).

The second strategy maps over a list of arrays, so `count_even_numbers` is called for every array in the list.

Comment: Good point, Roland, that resolves the mystery and seems obvious in hindsight. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out your example fits perfectly in the [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) model. Compiling the following source code `count_even.py`:

```
#pythran export count_even(int [:])
import numpy as np

def count_even_numbers(x):
    return np.where(np.mod(x, 2) == 0, 1, 0)

def count_even(arr):
    s = 0
    #omp parallel for reduction(+:s)
    for elem in arr:
        s += count_even_numbers(elem)
    return s
```

with the command line (-fopenmp activates the handling of the [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) annotations):

```
pythran count_even.py -fopenmp
```

And running `timeit` over this already yields massive speedups thanks to the conversion to native code:

**Without Pythran**

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; arr = np.arange(1e7, dtype=int); from count_even import count_even' 'count_even(arr)'
verryyy long, more than several minutes :-/
```

**With Pythran, one core**

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; arr = np.arange(1e7, dtype=int); from count_even import count_even' 'count_even(arr)'
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 msec per loop
```

**With Pythran, two cores**:

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; arr = np.arange(1e7, dtype=int); from count_even import count_even' 'count_even(arr)'
100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 msec per loop
```

twice as fast, parallelization is working :-)

Note that OpenMP enables multi-threading, not multi-processing.