# Split several times a numpy array into irregular fragments

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, split

As the title of the question suggests, I am trying to find an optimal (and possibly pythonic) way of splitting several times a one dimensional numpy array into several irregular fragments, provided the following conditions: the first split occurs into `n` fragments whose lengths `l` are contained in the `LSHAPE` array, the second split occurs in each one of the `n` previous fragments, but now each one of them is split regularly into `m` arrays. The corresponding values of `m` are stored in the `MSHAPES` array, in a way that the *i-th* `m` matches the *i-th* `l`. To best illustrate my problem, I include the solution I have found so far, which makes use of the numpy [split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) method:

```
import numpy as np

# Define arrays (n = 3 in this example)

LSHAPE = np.array([5, 8, 3])
MSHAPE = np.array([4, 5, 2])

# Generate a random 1D array of the requiered lenght

LM_SHAP = np.sum(np.multiply(LSHAPE, MSHAPE))
REFDAT = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=LM_SHAP)

# Split twice the array (this is my solution so far)

SLICE_L = np.split(REFDAT, np.cumsum(np.multiply(LSHAPE, MSHAPE)))[0:-1]
SLICE_L_M = []
for idx, mfrags in enumerate(SLICE_L):
    SLICE_L_M.append(np.split(mfrags, MSHAPE[idx]))
```

In the code above a random test array (`REFDAT`) is created to fulfill the requirements of the problem, and then subsequently split. The results are stored in the `SLICE_L_M` array. This solution works, but I think is hard to read and possibly not efficient, so I would like to know if it is possible to improve it. I have read some Stackoverflow threads which are related to this one (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049072/how-to-efficiently-split-scipy-sparse-and-numpy-arrays-into-smaller-n-unequal-ch) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922395/python-numpy-split-array-into-unequal-subarrays)) but I think my problem is slightly different. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

## Edit:

One can gain an average ~ 3% CPU time improvement if a list comprehension is used:

```
SLICE_L = np.split(REFDAT, np.cumsum(np.multiply(LSHAPE, MSHAPE)))[0:-1]
SLICE_L_M = [np.split(lval, mval) for lval, mval in zip(SLICE_L, MSHAPE)]
```

Comment: `np.split` via `np.array_split` does a `alist.append(arr[st:end])` in a loop.  There's some added complexity because it can split on different axes, but at its core it's just a repeated slicing.  As long as the fragments are irregular you can't do anything more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Still, the code I wrote looks very cumbersome, not obvious. Maybe this is all one can do, but I am curious if a more clever/simpler implementation exists.